# C++ basic constructor question

Tags: c++, constructor, templates, vector

*How should I handle the following situation :*

I am writing my own 2D vector class and have the following code:

```
class Vector2 : public (...)
public:

   Vector2(float x, float y) {

      local_vector_storage_[0] = x;
      local_vector_storage_[1] = y;
   }

   template <typename Iterator> Vector2(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {

      ASSERT(end - begin == 2);

      resize(2);

      std::copy(begin, end, local_vector_storage_.begin());
   }

// ...
};
```

Now if I say `Vector2 v(3.0f, 4.0f);` it compiles fine and calls the appropriate float constructor.

But if I write `Vector2 v(3, 4);` it fails because the templated iterator constructor *"fits better"* and `Vector2(Iterator(3), Iterator(4))` is called.

**What should I do in this case?**

*My idea was about introducing `assign(It1, It2)` member method instead of the constructor but maybe there is a better solution?*

### Edit:

Also, what do you think about `ASSERT(end - begin == 2)` line? I know that this means I can't, for example, pass iterators of `std::list`, but brings additional safety. Should I do this or not?

Comment: Good question! I see only three options: 1. Use a range instead of iterators; 2. add an explicit `(int, int)` constructor; 3. leave the class as-is and require explicit floats. You might also consider adding free-standing factory functions such as `make_vector`.

Comment: Concering your question about `assert`: you can use `std::distance` instead. Or maybe pass just one iterator since you always copy a constant number of elements anyway.

Comment: What is the type of local_vector_storage_? I guess it's some vector but vector of what? The class itself is not a template so the type of the vector is probably fixed right? BTW. What are You actually trying to do?

Comment: For your assert, you could use `std::distance` instead of subtraction, so it'd work with all iterator types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this seems to work:

```
template<typename T>
struct notnumeric {typedef int OK;};

template<>
struct notnumeric<int> {};

class Vector2
{
public:
   Vector2(float x, float y)
   {
   }

   template <typename Iterator>
   Vector2(Iterator begin, Iterator end, typename notnumeric<Iterator>::OK dummy = 0)
   {
   }
};
```

I believe it's using SFINAE to prevent the compiler selecting the second ctor for non-numeric types.

As for `ASSERT (end - begin == 2)`, I think you should be using `std::distance(begin, end)` to determine the distance between two iterators.

Comment: You can improve it by using `std::enable_if<!std::is_numeric<Iterator>::value, Iterator>::type`. This will remove the "dummy" parameter and uses compiler-provided (or Boost, if you're desperate) type traits, which are much more reliable than custom-written type traits. In addition, you could throw, instead of using assert.

Comment: Agreed that is better (if it works), though i think `enable_if` is only in boost until C++0x.

Comment: @DeadMG: How can enable_if remove the dummy on a constructor? I thought that only worked on methods with return types.

Comment: @Staffan: Enable_if works wherever a type declaration may be used. In this case, the arguments. People just use the return types most commonly. @Jon Hanson: It's in TR1 too.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Is this a 2d vector?  Or just two vectors?  I answered this for a 2d vector.

> How should I handle the following situation

I think you should handle it by removing the `float` constructor.  From reading the code, it's unclear what kind of object you should expect from this.

From reading the callsite code, I would have no reason to believe that `vector2 v2(1, 5);` creates a vector of two vectors, each with one value.

Personally, I would have expected it to create a `1x5` matrix.

If this is a common use case for your library, consider a [named constructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.8):

```
vector2 Create2x1(float f1, float f2);
```

> re: ASSERT

The ASSERT is a nice sanity check, but requires your `Iterator` to support random access (or at least subtraction to find distance).  This might overly restrict its usage.  Consider using a `std::distance` or checking that `local_vector_storage` is size two afterwards.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me that `vector v2(1, 5)` is constructing a 2-dimensional vector with one dimension having magnitude 1 and the other 5. The `local_vector_storage` member holds the scalar values of each dimension not other vectors. OP could change that name, but the vector API makes sense (at least to me!)

Comment: @Neil : Hmmm... now I'm thoroughly confused.  Maybe you're right, but why make the dimensions floats?  Maybe so it compiles?  Assigning `x` and `y` to the local_storage seems weird since the actual storage is never resized.

Answer (score 1):

In the particular case I see no sense of introducing the `Vector2(Iterator begin, Iterator end)` c'tor at all.

In general, I see no sense to mimic the `std::vector` (which is essentially a wrapper for an array) when the dimension of your `Vector2` is fixed and never change. Overlap of use-cases between the `std::vector` and your `Vector2` is negligible to non-existent: `std::vector` is often initialized from another container, while the `Vector2` would be 50/50 initialized with two values or with another Vector2.

And even if your decide to go ahead, the line:

```
ASSERT(end - begin == 2);
```

would drastically limit usefulness of the constructor, as relatively few iterators support the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

For the [call resolution here is a detailed why from Herb Sutter](http://gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm)